# Pandas: Select data between Sunday 23:00-Friday 23:00 (1 year span)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, datetimeindex

I have the timeseries of Euro-US Dollar Exchange Rate at minute granularity spanning the entire 2015 year, including non-trading days (ex.weekends) where the timeseries value get repeated for the entire non-trading period.

I need to discard such periods by selecting only the data between Sunday 23:00 pm and Friday 23:00 pm.

I haven't found a solution yet for Pandas (I know how to select between times inside a day and select between days). I could simply shift the time by 1h and then select only the business days but this is a sub-optimal solution.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Example of data:

```
Local time,              Open,    High,    Low,     Close,   Volume
02.01.2015 22:58:00.000, 1.20008, 1.20016, 1.20006, 1.20009, 119.84
02.01.2015 22:59:00.000, 1.20009, 1.20018, 1.20004, 1.20017, 40.61
02.01.2015 23:00:00.000, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 0
02.01.2015 23:01:00.000, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 0
...
04.01.2015 22:58:00.000, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 0
04.01.2015 22:59:00.000, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 1.20017, 0
04.01.2015 23:00:00.000, 1.19495, 1.19506, 1.19358, 1.19410, 109.4
04.01.2015 23:01:00.000, 1.19408, 1.19414, 1.19052, 1.19123, 108.12
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df` and `pd.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` `tidx`

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((tidx.shape[0], 2)), tidx, columns=list('AB'))
```

we can construct a series of values for which to filter

```
day_hour = (((tidx.weekday + 1) % 7) * 100) + tidx.hour
```

determine which values are prior to Friday 23:00

```
before_friday = day_hour <= 523
```

And after Sunday 23:00

```
after_sunday = day_hour >= 23
```

Filter our `df` based on above conditions

```
df[before_friday & after_sunday]
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared, this seems a good solution but it is for hourly data so I've modified the following:

Comment: tidx = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', freq='1min')
before_friday = day_hour <= 522

Comment: This works with your dummy array df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((tidx.shape[0], 2)), tidx, columns=list('AB')) but on my original array I have the following problem:
"ValueError: Item wrong length 525601 instead of 525540."

Comment: Apologies for the multiple comments but I'm still a StackOverflow newbie (pressed enter to go next line and instead it posted the comment) and it doesn't provide me with an edit button.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I don't mind multiple comments.

Comment: I further modified your code to match the length of the 2 arrays (525601 vs 525540) with the following command: tidx = pd.date_range('2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 22:59:00', freq='1min'). However I've realized that the final code isn't working properly, I checked the month of May and the week-end values don't get filtered properly. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed by using the index of my dataframe with df.index = tidx